# Excel vba - convert string to number

Tags: string, vba, numbers, vlookup

So, I used the left function to take the first 4 characters of a string and I need to run a vlookup with it, but it won't find the match because it's looking through numbers.

I want to do this in a macro, so I'm not sure about the syntax. Can someone help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use the [val()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/val-function-HA001228931.aspx) function

Answer (score 5):

If, for example, x = 5 and is stored as string, you can also just:

x = x + 0

and the new x would be stored as a numeric value.